# Tomcat Jersey NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, jersey, http-status-code-500

I have an Tomcat 9.0.20 server running on my computer with JDK 12 and Jersey 2 as REST API helper. This works fine.
But when I deploy the files to my Ubuntu server, which is running the same tomcat and Java Version, I get an error 500:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)

Root Cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:306)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:292)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:291)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:258)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:346)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingR
```

I used these libraries:

[image: used libraries]

I used Jhades to detect overlapping libraries but this didn't help me.

```
>> jHades - scanning classpath for overlapping jars: 

WARNING: this classloader is not supported: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
WARNING: this classloader is not supported: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>de.kai.iae</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My Hello.Java:

```
package de.kai.iae;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of jsr311-api jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues:

- You must not put application jars inside tomcat's `./lib` folder. Instead you should add those jars as dependencies for each application inside `<WAR>/WEB-INF/lib` In that way your applications will be independent and will be able to use different versions of those libraries.
- Make sure you do not package several versions of the same dependency, which will most probably cause various class-loading issues such as `ClassNotFoundException`, `NoClasDefFoundError` and `NoSuchMethodError`

For instance you have `jakarta.ws.rs-api` wich is Jax-Rs version 2, but you also have `jsr311-api` which is Jax-Rs version 1.

So in your case, some jersey code tries to call [getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getProperties--) which was introduced in JaxRs-2, but the JVM has loaded the `Application` class from `jsr311-api` which is JaxRs-1 where that method does not exist.So removing the `jsr311-api` jar should fix the problem.